# MDM Cube browsing Fast vs Excel pivot being too slow

Tags: ssas, excel-pivot, multidimensional-cube

I have a MDM cube with fact having just 84K records. Simple STAR schema structure. All regular relationships and no calculations or KPIs.

While trying to browse the cube by pulling 15-20 attributes from various dimensions with no filters applied, cube gives result in less than 10-12 seconds, which is awesome.

**While reading the cube through Excel pivot, as soon as the attribute count goes beyond 8 or so, cube becomes slow to a point wherein if we bring in even a single attribute in column labels, it takes forever to respond, sometimes even crashes.**

Has anyone faced such issue before and what could be a solution or workaround?

PS: I know for a fact that Excel creates a very complex MDX query to retrieve data from MDM cube which otherwise can be extracted using a simpler MDX.

Comment: Most likely it's the empty combinations that are causing it. When you browse the cube it eliminates the empty combinations using non empty